# A common way to multiply numpy array of arrays or 2D array by a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get a result of
ax = as_x-aseg_3d*aline_a

where as_x and aline_a are numpy vectors, and aseg_3d is an array of arrays. as_x.shape and aline_a shape are (S,), and aseg_3d shape is also shown as (S,) as it should be for array of arrays. The result ax is also an array of arrays with the same shape as aseg_3d.

The problem is, that aseg_3d is an array of arrays because the arrays inside have different lengths. However, sometimes they don't and than aseg_3d becomes just a 2D array. The mutliplication above then fails on ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (S,N).

I can fix it by doing:
ax = as_x[:,None]-aseg_3d*aline_a[:,None]

but this does not work in the same way for the previous case when I have an array of arrays.

Is there a way to make it work in both cases: array of arrays and 2D array?

Or perhaps there is a way to keep a numpy array of arrays dtype="object" even if all the inner arrays have the same length?

Btw. I was trying to do the above multiplication with list comprehensions, which would always work, but it is much slower.

Thank you for all advice!

Answer (score 0):

### Expression that works in either case:

You can utilize the transpose. Simple case (just multiplication):

```
(vector * vec_of_vecs_or_2D.T).T
```

Full OP example:

```
(vector1 - vector2 * vec_of_vecs_or_2D.T).T
```

### Example:

```
>>> v = np.array([3, 5])
>>> A = np.array((*map(np.array,[[1,2],[1,2,3]]),))
>>> B = np.array([[1,2,4],[1,2,3]])
>>> 
>>> v
array([3, 5])
>>> A
array([array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
>>> B
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> 
>>> (v*B.T).T
array([[ 3,  6, 12],
       [ 5, 10, 15]])
>>> (v*A.T).T
array([array([3, 6]), array([ 5, 10, 15])], dtype=object)
```

### How it works:

If `vec_of_vecs_or_2D` is 1D of object dtype then the transpose does nothing.

If `vec_of_vecs_or_2D` is genuinely 2D then the transpose moves the axis matching `vector` to the end, so `vector` is properly broadcast, and back again afterwards.

### Why it's cheap:

Please note that the transpose in `numpy` is lazy. It does not actually move any data, it just "swaps the axis labels".

For example taking the transpose of a `1000x1000` array takes ~200 ns on my laptop:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1_000_000).reshape(1000, 1000)
>>> timeit(lambda: a.T)
0.22008929261937737
```

### Alternatively, force array of arrays in any case:

Example

```
>>> L1 = [np.arange(i, 2*i+2) for i in range(3)]
>>> L2 = [np.arange(i, i+3) for i in range(3)]
>>> L1
[array([0, 1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4, 5])]
>>> L2
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4])]
```

Method 1 (ugly but simple):

```
>>> A1 = np.array([*L1, None])[:-1]
>>> A2 = np.array([*L2, None])[:-1]
>>> A1
array([array([0, 1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
>>> A2
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Method 2: (not quite as ugly but complicated)

```
>>> A1 = np.frompyfunc(L1.__getitem__, 1, 1)(range(len(L1)))
>>> A2 = np.frompyfunc(L2.__getitem__, 1, 1)(range(len(L2)))
>>> A1
array([array([0, 1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
>>> A2
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! But on the side, do you know if there is a way to create an array of arrays with same dimensions?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add that I am forced to use Python 2.7, so the methods with stars give an error. Thus the complicated method needs to be used. I have yet another question, if you don't mind.

Comment: I need to calculate np.arctan2(y,x), where y and x are arrays of arrays (or not, as in the original question). So I can loop through arrays with list comprehension which always works, or use a slightly (10-20%) faster np.frompyfunc(np.arctan2, 2, 1)(y,x). However, the latter again works fast only for array of arrays, while is 10 times slower when array of arrays beomces a 2D array. I can solve it with the way of forcing array of arrays that you just gave me, but maybe you know a pretty way like for the original question?

Comment: @LechWiktorPiotrowski Actually, I'd just `try` `np.arctan2(y, x)` which should work and be fast for homogeneous 2D arrays and put your `np.frompyfunc(np.arctan2, 2, 1)(y, x)` in the except branch.

Comment: Thanks! Actually surprisingly the speed is roughtly the same in both cases here.

Comment: @LechWiktorPiotrowski It's not super-surprising. Often, it suffices to have the inner-most loop vectorized to benefit from 90% of the speed of numpy. For example, `frompyfunc(np.arctan` etc. is slow on proper NxM arrays, because it calls `np.arctan` with all the overhead that a Python function call entails for every single element, i.e. NM times. For arrays of arrays the call is only made N times while the inner iteration happens in compiled code. Since the payload for each Python function call is reasonably large in this case the overhead in relative terms becomes much less significant.